# Correct way to reference Boolean pointers each other in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

I was looking for way to solve this small Boolean pointer references problem but cannot came to a solution. I know C++ becomes complex when it comes to  usage of Pointers and references.

Below code fragments uses a flow like references of `bool*` and I want to assign the temp5 value (which is `true`) to the bool* all the way to temp and print it. However this ends up with segmentation fault. Would like to know what has gone wrong or what am I missing about pointers and references when in a situation like this. Thank You!

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  bool* temp= nullptr;
  bool* temp2;
  bool* temp3;

  temp2 = temp;
  temp3=temp2;

  bool temp5 = true;
  *temp3 = temp5;

  std::cout << *temp <<std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I see no references here.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I suppose that was an English word, not a C++ word :)      
P. S. Is that the Vulcan girl from Star Trek Enterprise on your avatar?..

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: It's me! (yes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning value to a `nullptr`. That is what is causing segmentation fault

Just replace line

```
bool* temp = nullptr;
```

with this

```
bool* temp= new bool;
```

It will work now.

And don't forger to delete it with `delete` operator.

Comment: @Violet Giraffe Thanks, Corrected my answer

Comment: Thank you. This worked. Somewhat new to this `new bool`. Thanks for mentioning the memory leak. I think deleting it should solve it.

Comment: @IsuraNirmal as soon as you feel confident to do so, please read up on `unique_ptr`. It may look slightly advanced at this stage, but it is the recommended way to avoid memory leaks.

Answer (score 4):

Your `temp3` is left uninitialized. Dereferencing it is likely to cause access violation. And `temp` is `nullptr`, dereferencing it (especially - assigning by pointer) is also forbidden. In other words, you have a whole lot of pointers but all of them point nowhere.

Moreover, it's unclear what this code should actually do.
Did you want something like this?

```
int main()
{
  bool value = false;

  bool* temp= &value;
  bool* temp2;
  bool* temp3;

  temp2 = temp;
  temp3=temp2;

  bool temp5 = true;
  *temp3 = temp5;

  std::cout << *temp <<std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Or just `temp3 = &temp5`?

Comment: @Ben temp3 = &temp5 also caused the seg fault. Can this behaviour be explained?

Comment: @IsuraNirmal: `temp3 = &temp5` is a perfectly valid operation of storing the address of `temp5` variable in `temp3` pointer. Which specific line caused the segfault? I'm sure it wasn't this one.

Comment: `temp3 = &temp5` caused seg fault in one machine(`*temp3 = temp5` worked fine in that machine) but perfectly worked well in another.(that machine dereferencing didnt work)  

What could be the cause for this? compiler versions?